# EditText is not editable inside Genymotion emulator

Tags: android-edittext

I am unable to type inside my EditText, and I'm not sure why. I've tried typing in it both with and without a hint, and also, both with and without hardcoded text (to be deleted). When there is hardcoded text, I can delete it, but I cannot add new text. When there is a hint, if I type in the EditText, the new text is not displayed, the hint stays in place, and the cursor focus leaves the EditText.
*note - I also attempted this first with a SearchView control instead of an EditText, and I also could not type in the SearchView. I would be so grateful if someone could answer why this behavior happens. Here is the EditText and a button next to it:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtSearch"
    android:editable="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:hint="Search"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_Search"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/action_search_select"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have set a listener for the button onClick(), but no listeners are set for the EditText. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered that this issue was not really happening, but it just seems that way on my Genymotion emulator. I assembled a debug .APK file and installed on my actual device to figure this out, and sure enough, all controls accept input without issue. Seems Genymotion emulator may have some bugs.